# Generating a palindrome number taken from input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a program that takes a number from input and generates it's palindrome number. My program only prints the first half not the second. I tried reverse, didnt work.I have incluede those lines as comment.

My Code:

```
def show_palindrome(maximum):
    maximum = int(input("Enter Number : "))
    for number in range(1, maximum + 1):
        temporary = number
        reverse = 0
    
        while (temporary > 0):
            reminder = temporary % 10
            reverse = (reverse * 10) + reminder
            temporary = temporary //10

        if(number == reverse):
            #number2 = number[::-1]
            #print(number,number2, end = '')
            print(number, end = '')

show_palindrome(3)
```

My output:

```
123
```

The output I need:

```
12321
```

Comment: For you, what is the `3` you're passing as parameter ? As it's overwrited by the `int(input())` call

Comment: What is the input frmo the user `3` or `123` ?

Comment: What output would you want if the input was an even length string? - e.g '1234'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
def show_palindrome(maximum = None):
    if not maximum:
        maximum = input("Enter Number : ")
        
    output = str(maximum)
    for number in range(1, int(maximum)):

        output = str(int(maximum) - number) + str(output) + str(int(maximum) - number)

        
    return output

print(show_palindrome(3))
```

this returns `12321` for instance

A couple of things I would do differently in your function:

1. If you're going to require the input in the def (The way you make it optional is to set it equal to something when you declare it like I have it set to None (maximum=None), then you don't need the input() statement.
2. Since you already know how long you want it to be ( you require it declared when you initialize the function, it's just 2*maximum - 1) there's really no need to use a while loop.

Other than that good job! Keep it up!

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems over complicated, and I don't even know what to fix in it. What I can tell is that passing a parameter `maximum` to overwrite it just after with `maximum = int(input("Enter Number : "))` is useless, don't pass the parameter.

---

So let's back to easy things

1. Build palindrome using strings method : slicing backwards from index `-2`, and reverse it with `-1` increment

   ```py
   def show_palindrome():
       value = input("Enter Number : ")
       print(value + value[-2::-1])
   ```
2. Build palindrome using math operations : save the remainder, except the first one

   ```py
   def show_palindrome():
       value = input("Enter Number : ")
       result = value

       value = int(value) // 10  # remove last char which would be redundant
       while value > 0:
           result += str(value % 10)
           value = value // 10

       print(result)

   show_palindrome()
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something simpler like this:

```
def show_palindrome():
    num = input("Enter Number : ")
    print(num + num[:-1][::-1])
        
show_palindrome()
```

Input:

```
123
12
1
```

Output:

```
12321
121
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the `string slice method` (as used by @PApostol), you could also use the `reversed` method :

```
def show_palindrome():
    value = input("Enter Number : ")
    print(value[:-1] + "".join(reversed(value)))
```

**Input:**

```
123
```

**Output:**

```
12321
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def palindrome(maximum):
    number = ''.join([str(num) for num in range(1, maximum + 1)])
    return int(number + number[-2::-1])

print(palindrome(3))
```

Output:

```
12321
```